# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting data input validation

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently trying to make a google sheets where Column A is a Date and Column B,C,D,E Are relevant info according to that date. I am wondering how it is possible to highlight cells B-E in the same row if two criteria are met:

1. If column A of that row is not blank.
2. If any cell in B-E is blank to highlight them red.

Basically it is a way for showing there should be data there if there is a data (A date) in column A. I can do this for a single row, but I cant find a way to apply this to all of the sheet until the EOF.

Thanks,

Example of single row:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 0):

Use custom formula for CF:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A2<>"")*($B2:$E2=""))
```

apply formatting to B2:E

[image]

#### References

- [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)
- [Google Sheets conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)